# phpMyAdmin: Make foreign relation more readable

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am adding some foreign relations in phpMyAdmin to make data more easily accessible when adding rows. How can I make the foreign relation value stay as is (ex. ad6c68d9c365364f437e4a569765de2e) but make the text show the more readable 'name' value of the linked table?

Here is what it looks like now:

[image: what it looks like now]

I want the calling value to **show** something like 'junior', the name value of the displayed data, but I want the value to remain as is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is; as far as I can tell from the phpMyAdmin instances to which I have access, you'd have to modify the phpMyAdmin source so as to have the query used to generate this view include a `JOIN` on the table containing the data you want displayed. Theoretically possible, but difficult and not really advisable in practice.